sdkman installation fails on mcOS
Trying to install sdkman on a mac M1
Excuting this line
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash

consistently fails here:
Looking for a previous installation of SDKMAN...
Looking for unzip...
Looking for zip...
Looking for curl...
Looking for sed...
Installing SDKMAN scripts...
Create distribution directories...
Getting available candidates...
'SDKMAN_CANDIDATES_CSV=$(curl -s "${SDKMAN_SERVICE}/candidates/all")': command failed with exit code 56.

switching from -s to -k or zsh to bash to adding sudo gives the same result.
I am using OH-MY-ZSH

Can you run this command to see what you get : curl -s google.com ?

Download the script first so you can debug or modify it, instead of piping it. Run with bash -x so you can see the debug output.

@Philippe curl -s google.com does not come back with anything but seems to execute successfully
@DiegoTorresMilano not so verse is bash but running bash -x after getting the script just output the whole script.

curl -s google.com should output a minimum HTML. If not, check your network configuration.

Changing network did get me better result:
`
301 Moved
301 Moved
The document has moved
here.
`
zsh has nothing to do with this. The initial curl works fine, and its output is successfully piped to and executed by bash.
